# How can I quit an FTP session without closing the cmd window

Tags: ftp, cmd

The "close" line below is closing the cmd window. Is there a way to end the FTP session and remain in cmd so I can continue my script and rename the file?

```
h:
cd profile\desktop\testfolder
@ftp -i -s:"%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
open 192.XXX.X.XXX
username
pw
cd /user/data/
binary
mget testfile.txt
close
ren testfile.txt testfile_%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%.txt
exit
```

Comment: Use "quit" instead of "close"

Comment: You maybe want to do "prompt off" before your "mget" so it doesn't ask you stupid questions about whether you want to do what you asked like a stupid Windows box would.